# Query Not working in MySQL 5.6 - [MYSQL 5.1 (Master) to MYSQL 5.6 (Slave) Replication Error]

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, master-slave

MYSQL 5.1 (Master) to MYSQL 5.6 (Slave) Replication Error

Below Query not working in MYSQL 5.6 which is working fine with MYSQL 5.1

mysql> alter table MY_DATA add column test enum('0','1') default 0 after channel_id;

ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'test'

Comment: Try providing default `'0'` instead of `0`

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between '0' & 0 Is there any syntax issue with 5.6 because the same query is working fine with 5.1

Answer (score 0):

The same is resolved after running below query 
alter table MY_DATA add column test enum('0','1') default '0' after channel_id;

(Used '0' instead of 0 after default)